# Loading scripting languages files at modules in Python

Tags: python, ruby, scripting, interpreter

I need some libraries to run code written in JavaScript, Ruby and other scrinting languages inside my application written in Python. I don't want to use converters or local webservice as solution.

Comment: Is this a statement of desire, or what is your question?

Comment: Does Python need to communicate with the other languages? Is this all in one program?

Comment: My app requires to run plugins written in lots of languages, not only python modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try running interpritator in shell (node.js for JS i guess) from python and parsing results.
It's impossible to create bindings to modules and functions of other interpetative language as far as I know.